# What is the difference between Console.WriteLine('single quote'); and Console.WriteLine("double quote");

Tags: c#, .net, console

Why Visual Studio throw an error on

```
Console.WriteLine('string with single quote');
```

And not on :

```
Console.WriteLine("string with double quote");
```

?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) are used for the `char` data type which can only take a single character, hence the name, exempting escaped values such as `'\n'`, `'\r'`, etc., which are still represent a single `char` when compiled.

A double quote (`"`), is used to denote a UTF-16 encoded string (2 bytes [generally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) per character, not `ASCII`, and is not .NET's default - UTF-16), but cannot handle all known character sets ([UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)).

Comment: Too generalized, this is perfectly legal: `Char c = '\t';`

Comment: @TimSchmelter well yes and no. Your example still results in a single character being stored. The `\t` is the escape code for a tab character.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that a charcter literal does not need to have a single char, there are some escape-sequences. Maybe nitpicking ;)

Answer (score 1):

Console.WriteLine('') will accept char literal. so when you will try to pass more than 1 chars it will generates an error.

While Console.WriteLine("") will accept a string which can contain words.